# Crash on re-opening app when application class is killed

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am using an application class for saving my data after parsing to have acces to it in my entire application. This works very good for me. There is only one problem:

If I stopped using my application and some time later, when i used some other apps, Android sometimes has killed the application class (i think) because when i reopen my application i get an nullpointerexception error, because data im loading doesn't exist anymore.

I know that this is what Android does: killing apps if it needs memory, and i am not trying to avoid this or what so ever. 
But is there a way to kill my entire application when i lose my data from my application class?
So when i reopen my application, it just restarts the entire application (and reloads the data) instead of trying to reopen it, and crash because the missing data?

Comment: When it is reloading the data, what is missing making it to crash? Little more context please.

Comment: I think it is your database creation problem. How did you create database and table

Comment: Just a note - `class` cannot be killed nor run nor executed. `object` (which is **instance of** class) can.